# How to find the highest number among 3 pass integer parameters by using stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I tried with the below code, but unable to get the result. Can anyone help me out in the below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE highest_no
    (@a int,
     @b int,
     @c int)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @highest varchar()

    IF (@a > @b) AND (@a > @c)
    THEN PRINT @a;

    ELSIF (@b > @a) AND (@b > @c)
    THEN PRINT @b;

    ELSE PRINT @c
END

DECLARE @a1 int, @b1 int, @c1 int

SET @a1 = 5
SET @b1 = 4
SET @c1 = 6

EXEC highest_no @a1, @b1, @c1
```

I tried with the above code, but I'm unable to get the result. Can anyone help me out to find the highest number among 3 pass integer parameters by using stored procedure in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to "unpivot" them and then aggregate:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.Highest_Int @a int, @b int, @c int, @highest int OUTPUT AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @highest = MAX(i)
    FROM (VALUES(@a),(@b),(@c))V(i);
END;
GO

DECLARE @h int;

EXEC dbo.Highest_Int 1,2,3, @h OUTPUT;

PRINT @h;
```